# Android: Design consideration for performing background operation

Tags: android, xml-parsing, background-process

In my application, I am parsing XML data using SAX Parser. But, I want to put the whole parsing operation in background, i.e., I want to do this using worker thread. Which will be the best solution for this, using handler, AsyncTask or services, as I am having lots of confusion between the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Handler` doesn't do any work; it's a means for passing off processing between a background thread and the UI thread. An `AsyncTask` is the way to go here: it has a built-in `Handler` so you can do something back on the UI thread when you're done, or even publish updates as work progresses. It's just like using a plain worker `Thread`, but with the convenience of the `Handler` built in. Of course, you can use a worker `Thread` and `Handler` yourself if the way a `Handler` works isn't a good match to your needs.

A `Service` sounds like overkill for this; it's a way to make processing available to other activities. It also doesn't get around the problem: the `Service` is invoked on the UI thread and it needs to fire up a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You may just spawn a plain java thread and do the work there.

Answer (score 0):

all have their advantage .so answer any one out of all, is depends on your need ..

like if you want easy implementation can use `AsyncTask with predefined structure and callbacks` and so like services may have it's own advantage in certain case ..

Handler provide more flexibility then AsyncTask as AsyncTask have predefined structure and  callbacks for different work. So you can you `handler with any thread with` no predefined structure  and  callback limitation.